# unwanted space in Makefile

Tags: makefile

This will work

```
PREFIX=/home/tim/program_files/
# PREFIX=/opt/
PATH=$(PREFIX)mylib/
```

This will not work

```
PREFIX=/home/tim/program_files/ # PREFIX=/opt/
PATH=$(PREFIX)mylib/
```

because there is an unwanted space between `$(PREFIX)` and `mylib/`.

What is the related syntax rule of Makefile? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't point to a syntax rule *as such* but this detail is *specifically* called out in the makefile in the [`The Two Flavors of Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors) section.

> You can also use them to introduce controlled leading whitespace into variable values. Leading whitespace characters are discarded from your input before substitution of variable references and function calls; this means you can include leading spaces in a variable value by protecting them with variable references, like this:
>
> nullstring :=
>
> space := $(nullstring) # end of the line
>
> Here the value of the variable space is precisely one space. The comment ‘# end of the line’ is included here just for clarity. Since trailing space characters are not stripped from variable values, just a space at the end of the line would have the same effect (but be rather hard to read). If you put whitespace at the end of a variable value, it is a good idea to put a comment like that at the end of the line to make your intent clear. Conversely, if you do not want any whitespace characters at the end of your variable value, you must remember not to put a random comment on the end of the line after some whitespace, such as this:
>
> dir := /foo/bar    # directory to put the frobs in
>
> < Here the value of the variable dir is ‘/foo/bar    ’ (with four trailing spaces), which was probably not the intention. (Imagine something like ‘$(dir)/file’ with this definition!)